# Reactjs and react testing library

Tags: react-testing-library

after running "npm test"

getting the below error:

ReferenceError: Response is not defined while testing

Tried changing the  "testEnvironment": "jsdom" ==>  "testEnvironment": "node", still its not working.

"testEnvironment": "node",

Error

> jest --coverage

● Validation Warning:

Unknown option "compilerOptions" with value {"baseUrl": "src", "module": "commonjs", "target": "es6"} was found.
This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.

Configuration Documentation:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

● Validation Warning:

Unknown option "paths" with value {} was found.
This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.

Configuration Documentation:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

● Validation Warning:

Unknown option "compilerOptions" with value {"baseUrl": "src", "module": "commonjs", "target": "es6"} was found.
This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.

Configuration Documentation:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

● Validation Warning:

Unknown option "paths" with value {} was found.
This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.

Configuration Documentation:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

FAIL  src/testcases/Dashboard.test.js
● Test suite failed to run

```
ReferenceError: Response is not defined

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/msw/src/core/HttpResponse.ts:37:35)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/msw/src/core/index.ts:51:15)
```

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        19.732 s

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.